# Android 13 - How to show notification permission popup dialog before SFMC SDK initialisation

Tags: android, react-native, salesforce-marketing-cloud

We are using SFMC SDK with react native to show notification dialog popup to allow or don't allow the notification in android app.

react-native-marketingcloudsdk (version 7.4.x)
Android - 13 version
Android Target SDK - 33

Is there any way to initialise notification popup box before initialisation of react-native-marketingcould SDK to register a notification decision(allow/don't allow) ?

We had tried with below peace of code but no success.

```
 val launcher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
              contract = ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission(),
              onResult = { isGranted ->
                if (!isGranted) {
                  if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS)) {
                    rationalPermissionOpenDialog.value = true
                  } else {
                    permissionOpenDialog.value = true
                  }
                } else {
                  hasNotificationPermission = isGranted
                }
              }
            )
            if (rationalPermissionOpenDialog.value) {
              ShowRationalPermissionDialog(openDialog = rationalPermissionOpenDialog) {
                rationalPermissionOpenDialog.value = false
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
                  launcher.launch(Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS)
                }
              }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

- Upgrade your OneSignal SDK React Native version 4.4.0 +
- Validate your compile and target SDK version is at least version 33.

add this code where onesignal initialize

```
let areNotificationsEnabled = deviceState.areNotificationsEnabled();
 if (!areNotificationsEnabled) {
OneSignal.addTrigger("showPrompt", "true")}
```

https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-13-push-notification-developer-update-guide#step-3-add-notification-permission-prompt